# How do detect change in network type use in Phonegap / Cordova

Tags: javascript, networking, cordova

In Phonegap / Cordova 3.0, How do I detect a change in a network from 3G to Wi-Fi or vice versa. When changing, the offline event is not called because it quickly switches between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a Gist showing how to check the connection every x seconds from javascript. I don't know if it's the right approach for your usecase, but I needed this for an app recently: https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/10499328#file-connectionchecker-js